# A form is displaying as filled in, instead of blank, using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using an add on with Wordpress and it appears the PHP code is somehow calling my admin e-mail to autofill a form that is supposed to show up as blank.

Unfortunately for me, PHP is WAY over my head and I don't want to break everything.

```
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="stc-email"><?php _e( 'E-mail Address: ', 'stc_textdomain' ); ?></label>
              <input type="text" id="stc-email" class="form-control" name="stc_email" value="<?php echo !empty( $email ) ? $email : NULL; ?>"/>
          </div>
```

I just want the form to be blank, but it's autofilling with the admin e-mail on the Wordpress account. I've targeted the line of code, I think it has something to do with this bit:

```
value="<?php echo !empty( $email ) ? $email : NULL; ?>"/>
```

But I don't think

```
!empty
```

is working, nor is NULL, could anyone help out please?

Comment: Are you logged in to your site when you try it? If so log out or try it in a different browser and see if it is filled in. Chances are it won't be.

Comment: You're right - it's not. Is this normal, though? Or maybe just a bug within Wordpress itself? I guess it's not that big of a deal to live with it but I'd prefer to not have it at all.

Comment: It is normal and the line you posted that you thought was the "problem" is the reason it does it. That line checks to see if the variable named email is NOT empty. If it is NOT empty it shows the address. If it IS empty it will be blank. The email variable is populated when you log in to WordPress.

Comment: I am guessing, that $email is already used previously, so thats why it load (and not empty)

Comment: @Dave thank you for explaining.